# How to pass an object to AngularJS factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in edit state i am trying to update riskDto but i am getting an error about some object i dont know what i am doing wrong please help.

Code tried so far...

ctrl.js

```
RiskService.saveAllignRiskToProcess($scope.riskDTO,$stateParams.processKey).then(function (response) {
            if ($scope.editMode) {
                $scope.hideYesBtn = true;
                $scope.hideNoBtn = true;
                $scope.showOkBtn = true;
                $scope.messageText = 'Updated Risk Within Process successfully';
                $scope.confirmationWin.open().center();
                $scope.okCallback = $scope.riskAlignToProcessBack;
            }
}
});
```

facotry.js

```
saveAllignRiskToProcess: function(processKey) {
        return $http.post('app/risk/rest/riskTocontrol/saveCreateAndAlignNewRiskToProcess/' + processKey);
      }
```

state.js

```
.state('createAndAlignRisk', {
                url: '/risk/cnaRsk/:processKey',
                templateUrl: 'views/risk/createNewRisk.html',
                controller: 'RiskCtrl',
                data: {
                    authenticate: true
                }

            })
```

consoleError

```
/riskTocontrol/saveCreateAndAlignNewRiskToProcess/[object%20Object]
```

Comment: is processKey supposed to be an object or a string?

Comment: riskDto is an object

Comment: Seeing as when js calls toString() on it, it returns the object's toString() and not the string.

Comment: are you trying to post riskDTO with the process key then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass both object `$scope.riskDTO` , `$stateParams.processKey` to service then the your service method needs to be change along with caller method code

**Code**

```
RiskService.saveAllignRiskToProcess($scope.riskDTO,$stateParams.processKey)
 .then(function (response) {
  //..code here 
});
```

**Service**

```
  saveAllignRiskToProcess: function(processKey, riskDTO) {
     var url = 'app/risk/rest/riskTocontrol/saveCreateAndAlignNewRiskToProcess/' + processKey
     return $http.post(url ,JSON.stringify({ 'serverSideParamName': riskDTO}) );
  }
```

Comment: I have to pass riskDTO that will save new information to DTO object at backend

Comment: @aftab look at my edit, only you should replace `serverSideParamName` with your server side parameter name

Comment: ok risk is already aligned to process so if i am already in process and editing risk within process i should be just passing riskDTO object i believe.

Comment: i added state so you can see what exactly happening

Comment: @aftab I don't understand why you are relating state with this post call?

Comment: because i am using stateparams (processKey)

Comment: lets say i want to pass riskDTO how i can do that i took off $stateParams.processKey still getting that that error [object%object]

Comment: @aftab you are confused I think you should pass `$stateParams.processKey` key with `riskDTO` so server action will understand that.. And as per you current error it should not be apprear..could you update your question..whatever you tried till

Answer (score 1):

From [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

> post(url, data, [config]);
>
> data - Request content

The Data parameter is necessary that you can see from a documentation. You missed it in:

```
saveAllignRiskToProcess: function(processKey) {
        return $http.post('app/risk/rest/riskTocontrol/saveCreateAndAlignNewRiskToProcess/' + processKey);
      }
```